# AttributeError: 'Intents' object has no attribute 'message_content' в дискорд боте

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Хотел повторить обычный код [музыкального бота](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py) из официального GitHub discord.py. Вписал туда свой токен, но при запуске получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\DiscordMusic\bot.py", line 130, in <module>
    intents.message_content = True
AttributeError: 'Intents' object has no attribute 'message_content'
```

Мои настройки дискорд бота:
[image: Настройки]

Comment: Какая у вас версия библиотеки дискорд? Если не знаете точно, посмотреть можно, вставив в код строку `print(discord.__version__)`

Comment: @Xander, сегодняшняя, 1.7.3